# radio button on checked doesnt works

Tags: html, css

I am customizing a radio button with an icon, for which I have defined classes to my input and label elements. My checked property works when I define it as I

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
    -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

but not when I define it with its respective class names

```
.custom-radio:checked + .custon-radio-label:before{
    -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

I think it will not be feasible all the time to declare it with the element tag, can someone help me resolve this.

https://jsfiddle.net/rituk/b6m3vLt0/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.custom-radio-label` instead of `.custon-radio-label`...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct the spelling from `custon` to `custom`

```
.custom-radio:checked + .custom-radio-label:before{
    -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:checked` pseudo-class can be declared alone for all `:checked` elements or using a selector that can be `:checked`.

The reason the filter properties are not changing with your provided code are for two reasons:

- 'custon' should be spelled 'custom'
- Remove the `:before` pseudo-selector

The `:before` pseudo-class is undefined and non existant.
The element you are trying to change, as per noted with your first working example, is the label.

Learn more about the :checked pseudo-class here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked